# Drupal Bad url redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal-7

If the user types a bad URL they will be taken to our homepage.
for example: www.pardee.du.edu/badURL will take the user to http://pardee.du.edu.

can anyone plz help me out for that thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this module: https://drupal.org/project/r4032login.

Comment: Also there is Stack Exchange site for Drupal : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/. You should ask your Drupal questions there.

Comment: Also this module could be the thing you need: https://drupal.org/project/search404

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://pardee.du.edu/admin/config/system/site-information. There on the "Default 403 (access denied) page" and "Default 404 (not found) page" type "node". This will take you to front page.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in many ways.

1, Use a custom .htacess file and redirect 404s  to home page.
2, Use a Contrib Drupal module for redirection.